Should the “Get more details” links for the “I lost my password” option on the contact form link to help center rather than password recovery page?
In the contact form, we have an ‘I lost my password’ option in the “Account Issue” option.
If we click the lost password option, a pop-up will be shown:



If we click the “Get more details” option, it just links us to the password recovery page.
I expect, we can really get more details on this issue by clicking the link, but I didn’t. In my opinion, the password recovery page link should not be repeated twice.
I think the “Get more details” link should take us to a more useful place, maybe the help center: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reset-password
What do you think? Should we change the “Get more details” so it links to help center?
